# Метод расширения, с параметрами делегата

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Я понимаю что это возможно в некотором случае прозвучит глупо, но есть ли какие-то способы написать такой метод расширения, как например при передачи типа делегата универсальному методу *(Generic)*, вызвать сразу `Invoke` с параметрами делегата вместо его возврата?

Что бы получился примерно такой код, где вместо вызова Invoke, я бы передавал параметры делегату:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Delegate)]
public class CFunctionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string FunctionName { get; }

    public CFunctionAttribute(string functionName)
    {
        FunctionName = functionName;
    }
}
```

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[CFunction("avformat_open_input")]
internal delegate int FormatOpenInput(ref IntPtr codecContextPtr, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] filepath,
    IntPtr fmtPtr, ref IntPtr dictionary);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[CFunction("avformat_close_input")]
internal delegate void FormatCloseInput(ref IntPtr codecContextPtr);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[CFunction("av_dump_format")]
internal delegate void DumpFormat(IntPtr codecContextPtr, int index, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] url,
    int isOutput);
```

```
IntPtr avCodecContextPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
string path = Path.Combine("avformat-58.dll");
SafeLibraryHandle hModule = new FfmpegLibrary(path);
if (hModule.IsInvalid)
{
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
const string file = "SomePathToMedia";
IntPtr a = IntPtr.Zero;
int result = hModule.As<FormatOpenInput>().Invoke(ref avCodecContextPtr,
    file.ToCString(), IntPtr.Zero, ref a);
if (result < 0)
{

    return;
}

hModule.As<DumpFormat>().Invoke(avCodecContextPtr, 0, file.ToCString(), 0);
hModule.As<FormatCloseInput>().Invoke(ref avCodecContextPtr);
```

То что я хочу получить:

```
hModule.As<DumpFormat>(avCodecContextPtr, 0, file.ToCString(), 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете вызвать вот так

```
hModule.As<DumpFormat>()(avCodecContextPtr, 0, file.ToCString(), 0);
```

В c#7.3 можно ещё так извратиться

```
public static object InvokeAsDelegate<T>(this object obj, params object[] args) 
    where T : Delegate
{
    var @delegate = (Delegate) obj;
    return @delegate.DynamicInvoke(args); 
}
```

, но типы аргументов будут не проверены во время компиляции.